# Adding MKPlacemark addressDictionary to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios9

I'm trying to add a street address to my `UITableViewCell`'s textDetailLabel. The issue i'm having is how to capture the unique street address for each `cell` in the `Table View`.

Right now it's grabbing the first street value of the first instance in the dictionary and setting it as the street address for every `cell`.

I'm assuming I need to capture index i'm at and then retrieving the street value out of the dictionary, although i'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Here's my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    // searchResults is an array of MKMapItems
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row].name

    // the line that is causing me trouble 
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = placeMarkAddress["Street"] as? String ?? ""

    return cell

}


func searchQuery(query: String) {


    // request
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
    request.region = mapView.region

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    // search 
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) -> Void in

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        if(error != nil) {

            print(error?.localizedDescription)

        } else {

            // storing data about location in dictionary
            for item in (response?.mapItems)! {

                self.placeMarkAddress = item.placemark.addressDictionary!
                // prints expected results in console (not repeating, different for each MKMapItem)
                for (key,value) in self.placeMarkAddress {
                    print("\(key) -> \(value)")
                }
            }

            // storing the array of mkmapitems in the array
            self.searchResults = (response?.mapItems)!
        }


    }

}
```

[image: Address repeating]
The street address keeps repeating

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you post code into which you store in 'placeMarkAddress'? It may help more. I think you just replace 'placeMarkAddress' into for loop or any iteration code.

Comment: Posted. The `placeMarkAddress` is declared and initialized properly and is giving me the expected results in the console (not repeating, unique value for each `MKMapItem`)  The issue i'm having is how i'm going to capture each unique instance out of the dictionary and assign it into the `detailTextLabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create array of "placeMarkAddress".

```
var placeMarkAddress: NSMutableArray;
```

Now, add address into it.

```
for item in (response?.mapItems)! {
               self.placeMarkAddress.addObject(item.placemark.addressDictionary!)

 }
```

Comment: Yes! I created an array and in the same for loop where I initialize my dictionary I will populate my array with a list of addresses. Just remember to call the `removeAll(keepCapacity: boolean)` method to reset the dictionary AND array everytime `UISearchResultsUpdating ` is called. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get `MKmapItem's instance` for every `UITableViewCell` and then find `street address` from `MKmapItem's plcaemark`.

**Note** : code in Objective-C so make it to swift

```
MKmapItem *mapItem = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *itemAddressDictionary = mapItem.placemark.addressDictionary;
//get required string from itemAddressDictionary and set in cell.detailTextLabel
NSString *strStreet = [itemAddressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = strStreet;
```

Comment: I've already done that part and it works fine. The dictionary is already populated. The question is asking how to retrieve the information for each unique `MKMapItem`  when you can't specify the NSIndex.

Comment: @Mihado: You need to print like below..
Street,
City,
State.
right?

Comment: For each cell there will be NSIndexPath so there can't be any case here where there will be no NSIndexPath in UITableViewCell

Comment: I posted an image to show you how it repeats for every `cell`. @Paresh, there's no objectForKey method for dictionaries. What's the equivalent?

Comment: @Mihado : have you done changes as explained in answer because if not then result will be same as screenshot you send.